# List all page under sub site with Sharepoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sub-site, pages, csom

I try to get all pages under a subsite with javascript. I'm very new to Sharepoint. I built an object to handle these queries, but i can't retrieve the pages. I can get the Documents list.

Please check the "getPages()" method. It gives me a query error.

What did i do wrong? What's the best way to get it? How can i learn more about the Sharepoint CSOM?

Thank you very much!

```
var SPQueryHandler= function(url){
        var that = this;
        this.siteUrl = url;
        this.clientContext;
        this.isReady = false;
        this.fnStack = new Array();

        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(SP !== undefined){
                clearInterval(interval);
                that.init();    
            }
        },20);
    };

    SPQueryHandler.prototype.init = function(){
        var that = this;

        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(SP.ClientContext !== undefined){
                clearInterval(interval);

                that.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(that.siteUrl);
                that.clientContext.add_requestFailed(function (sender, args) {
                    alert('Request failed: ' + args.get_message());
                });

                that.isReady = true;

                if(that.whenReady !== undefined){
                    that.whenReady();
                }
            }
        });
    };

    SPQueryHandler.prototype.doWhenReady  = function(fn){
        if(typeof fn == 'function'){
            this.whenReady = fn;
        }
    };


    // http://allthatjs.com/2012/04/03/using-sharepoint-csom-in-html5-apps/
    SPQueryHandler.prototype.getDocuments = function(){
        var that = this;

        var web = that.clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
        var items = list.getItems('');
        var itemsArray = [];

        that.clientContext.load(items);
        that.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                itemsArray.push(item.get_fieldValues());
                console.log(item.get_fieldValues());
            }
            return itemsArray;
        });

    };

    SPQueryHandler.prototype.getPages = function(){
        var that = this;

        var web = that.clientContext.get_web();
        var webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser();

        that.clientContext.load(webCollection);
        that.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            log("getSubWebs query successful")
            alert("Number of sites: " + webCollection.get_count());
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why in `getPages` method you are getting sub sites (`SP.Web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser` method), but the following example shows how to retrieve list items from `Pages` library:

```
 SPQueryHandler.prototype.getPages = function(){
    var that = this;

    var web = that.clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');
    var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
    that.clientContext.load(items);
    that.clientContext.add_requestSucceeded(function()
    {
        var itemsValues = items.get_data().map(function(item){
            return item.get_fieldValues() 
        });
        console.log(itemsValues); //result
    });
    that.clientContext.executeQueryAsync();   
};
```

Comment: Works perfectly and i love your profile picture ^^
Alrigthy then

Comment: :)) One of my favorite: Mr. S. _Ventura_ AV _Yes Satan. Ohh, I thought you were someone else._

Comment: Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn Finkle Einhorn.... Einhorn is Finkle and Finkle is Einhorn